# Different auxiliary verbs for "leben" and "sterben"

Tags: etymology

> Ich habe gelebt
>
> Ich bin gestorben

To live and to die are opposites, yet in their perfect constructions one uses *sein* and the other uses *haben*, why?

The meanings of *leben* and *sterben* are related, being opposites, so you might (or at least I might) expect the auxiliaries to be the same.

Comment: From the English point of view, the fact that there is a choice between two auxiliaries is surprising (English has lost the perfect auxiliary *be*; it has survived in phrases such as *the time is come*).

Comment: Have you checked the general thumb rules for which German verbs use "sein" for their perfect tense? Or are you asking for these rules?

Answer (score 3):

> To live and to die are opposites

I suggest thinking of it differently: *living* is a state, and *being dead/non-existent* is a state, whereas *being born* or *dying* are transitions between the two states. Thus, *geboren sein* and *sterben* both conjugate with *sein*.

This logic may seem a bit contrived, since in German *geboren sein* is a kind of passive structure. Note however that the same logic applies in other languages, where being born and dying are both active actions: e.g., in French *naître* (to be born) and *mourir* (to die) both conjugate with auxiliary *être* (to be) rather than with *avoir* (to have). Moreover, unlike in German, the group of verbs that conjugate with *être* in French is very small, and includes exclusively *verbs of motion*.